# Using images downloaded from Freepik, pixabay etc

Tags: eula, derivative-work

Can I legally use static vector images downloaded from freepik or pixabay to create my own animations and then sell them? Their license terms are a bit confusing for me. They say that I can use those assets in personal and commercial projects as long as I include attribution. But at the same time they disallow selling any "derived work". Do my animations count as derived work?

What if I buy a pro account on these services, which frees me from including any attribution. Can I then create and sell such animations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### License to use does not mean license to create derivative works

These are different rights under copyright. If you want to make a derivative work, which your animations are, you must have a license to do so.

Comment: Thank you... so if I use those vector files in a website (after re-coloring, cropping etc.), that will not be seen as derived work?

Comment: Yes it would be

Comment: Then what does it even mean that I'm allowed to use it in my commercial projects? What am I allowed to do? Can I put that image into a website (without modification) and sell the website, but I can't sell the image (or the website) if I have modified the original image?

Comment: @dotNET yes - exactly